# Replacing JSON variables in BASH script

Tags: json, linux, bash

How exactly would I go about replacing JSON variables from a line in BASH?

For example, I have a variable in a file 'config.json'. The line is written as

```
"deviceId": "Raspberry Pi Node",
```

Is there an efficient way of replacing the variable from a line in the script so that it can be set and continue with the rest? I aim to only replace this with "RPi"

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It would be easiest to use the `jq` utility, or a higher language that can parse JSON (like Ruby, Python, Perl...). `jq` doesn't usually come with the system, but Ruby, Perl and Python typically do, these days. It is likely something can be hacked together using coreutils, but it would be hacky and fragile, without understanding of JSON structure.

Comment: Do you think I could get around this using sed? For example, 

sed -i 's/Raspberry Pi Node/RPi/g' config.json

Comment: Yes. But "something can be hacked together using coreutils, but it would be hacky and fragile". If you're sure that's the only place in config it appears, and that it will always have been that value before you change it, sure.

Comment: Thanks for your help! That'll certainly do the trick for me anyway!